# mount.cifs (cifs-utils): Where do the default options come from?

Tags: mount, samba, cifs, freenas, samba4

I have a FreeNAS 11.0-U4 box running a CIFS share, which I normally access from my Linux system via an autofs mount.  A few days ago, I noticed the mount misbehaving, displaying all files with useless DOS-style permissions (`rwxr-xr-x`) instead of the actual underlying mode bits.

I decided to try it out by hand.  I ran the `mount.cifs` commmand:

```
sudo mount.cifs -o username=theuser,uid=theuser,gid=theuser //theserver/theuser /mnt
```

Then I ran `mount` with no arguments to see what the actual mount looked like.  This came back:

```
//theserver/theuser on /mnt type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=3.0,cache=strict,username=theuser,domain=,uid=1000,forceuid,gid=1000,forcegid,addr=10.XX.XX.XX,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)
```

Note in particular the presence of `nounix` (which disables all UNIX extension support), `file_mode`, and `dir_mode`, all of which combine to force 0755 permissions on everything.

I am not specifying these options, and I'm pretty sure they're not lurking in a config file somewhere, so I'm very confused as to why they're appearing.  This setup used to work -- certainly well enough to archive files off to the NAS without it deciding that every file is executable.

On the Linux side, `mount.cifs` and the various samba components are version 4.6.7.  On the FreeNAS side, v11.0-U4 is running samba 4.6.8.

Where are these options coming from?  Do I need to tweak something on the server side?  How can I bludgeon things back into line?

Comment: I guess the defaults are hard-coded in mount.cifs. You can override the defaults by editing the mount options in `/etc/auto.smb`. It normally has a line at the top with `opts="-fstype=cifs"`. You can add comma-separated options there, like for example `opts="-fstype=cifs,file_mode=665,dir_mode=775"` etc.

Answer (score 1):

In kernel upgrade it was changed default verion of SMB protocol to 3.0 which doesn't understand to Unix extensions. If You want to use Unix extensions append to Your options "vers=1.0".

Comment: Okay, I downvoted this because it was "obviously" nonsense.  Today I actually tried it, and it worked.  What I don't understand is *why* it worked.  It's my understanding that UNIX extensions are independent of the CIFS protocol version.  Can you point to a reference documenting this limitation?

Comment: I can confirm it works with `vers=1.0`. BTW @ewhac you can remove the downvote by clicking the downvote button again.

Comment: Samba does not yet support unix extensions for SMB3 (in fact, SMB 2.0+). It is being worked on. [[lists.samba.org, 10/2017](https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2017-October/211517.html)]
When UNIX extensions will be finalized, the Samba implementation is ”not going to allow clients to create "real" symlinks on the server“. [[same thread](https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2017-October/211522.html)]

Comment: see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403509/how-to-enable-unix-file-permissions-on-samba-share-with-smb-2-0

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs) cifs can be manipulated with [proc](https://linux.die.net/man/5/proc)

> /proc/fs/cifs

and [fstab](https://linux.die.net/man/5/fstab)

> /etc/fstab

likely you want fstab, something like;

```
//theserver/theuser  /mnt   cifs    guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,vers=1.0  0  0
```

Comment: No, I _definitely_ don't want to do it through `fstab`, because I don't want the mount to persist.  I want it to appear and disappear on an as-needed basis.  This has to work on a laptop, which is constantly hopping networks.  `autofs` isn't a perfect solution, but it's worked better than anything else I've tried.